# Full url for an image-path in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, path

I have an Image, which contains carrierwave uploads:

```
Image.find(:first).image.url #=> "/uploads/image/4d90/display_foo.jpg"
```

In my view, I want to find the absolute url for this. Appending the [root_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939942/generate-full-url-to-javascript-in-rails-similar-to-javascript-path-but-url) results in a double `/`.

```
root_url + image.url #=> http://localhost:3000//uploads/image/4d90/display_foo.jpg
```

I cannot use [url_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489838/full-url-with-url-for-in-rails) (that I know of), because that *either* allows passing a path, *or* a list of options to identify the resource and the `:only_path` option. Since I do't have a resource that can be identified trough "controller"+"action" I cannot use the `:only_path` option.

```
url_for(image.url, :only_path => true) #=> wrong amount of parameters, 2 for 1
```

What would be the cleanest and best way to create a path into a full url in Rails3?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try `path` method

```
Image.find(:first).image.path
```

**UPD**

```
request.host + Image.find(:first).image.url
```

and you can wrap it as a helper to DRY it forever

```
request.protocol + request.host_with_port + Image.find(:first).image.url
```

Comment: That returns the entire (system) path. `=> "/home/..../public/uploads/image/4d90/foo.jpg"` I need the URL, not the path, for use in an atom feed.

Comment: oh yes. then try `request.host + Image.find(:first).image.url`

Comment: Also not :( `"localhost/uploads/image/4d90/display_foo.jpg"`  It misses the :3000-port (on development) and the http(s)://.

Comment: `request.protocol + request.host_with_port + Image.find(:first).image.url`

Comment: I am using delayed job to queue emailing jobs. The jobs renders emailing templates. However at this time the request will be nil (it is no longer part of an HTTP request as per se).

Answer (score 100):

You can also set CarrierWave's `asset_host` config setting like this:

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :file
  config.asset_host = ActionController::Base.asset_host
end
```

This ^ tells CarrierWave to use your app's `config.action_controller.asset_host` setting, which can be defined in one of your `config/envrionments/[environment].rb` files.  [See here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-controller) for more info.

Or set it explicitly:

```
  config.asset_host = 'http://example.com'
```

Restart your app, and you're good to go - no helper methods required.

* I'm using Rails 3.2 and CarrierWave 0.7.1

Comment: I like this, nice and clean

Answer (score 11):

Another simple method to use is URI.parse, in your case would be

```
require 'uri'

(URI.parse(root_url) + image.url).to_s
```

and some examples:

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > require 'uri'
 => true 
1.9.2p320 :002 > a = "http://asdf.com/hello"
 => "http://asdf.com/hello" 
1.9.2p320 :003 > b = "/world/hello"
 => "/world/hello" 
1.9.2p320 :004 > c = "world"
 => "world" 
1.9.2p320 :005 > d = "http://asdf.com/ccc/bbb"
 => "http://asdf.com/ccc/bbb" 
1.9.2p320 :006 > e = "http://newurl.com"
 => "http://newurl.com" 
1.9.2p320 :007 > (URI.parse(a)+b).to_s
 => "http://asdf.com/world/hello" 
1.9.2p320 :008 > (URI.parse(a)+c).to_s
 => "http://asdf.com/world" 
1.9.2p320 :009 > (URI.parse(a)+d).to_s
 => "http://asdf.com/ccc/bbb" 
1.9.2p320 :010 > (URI.parse(a)+e).to_s
 => "http://newurl.com"
```

Answer (score 5):

Just taking floor's answer and providing the helper:

```
# Use with the same arguments as image_tag. Returns the same, except including
# a full path in the src URL. Useful for templates that will be rendered into
# emails etc.
def absolute_image_tag(*args)
  raw(image_tag(*args).sub /src="(.*?)"/, "src=\"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}" + '\1"')
end
```

Comment: This helper works great within standard views, but you cannot use this in Mailer views, as Mailers have no sense of a "request", so your helper will fail.

Comment: True. I'm not sure, but I think with Rails 3.1 and the asset pipeline, you could use the asset host to put together full URLs. With earlier versions, I think one would need to hardcode the host.

Comment: @M.G.Palmer would this still work since carrierwave uploaded images reside inside the public folder?

Comment: @lulalala I should think so, maybe you'll need to call with something like absolute_image_tag("/../#{filename}") to get "up" from the default /images path. But I never used carrierwave so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a bunch of answers here. However, I didn't like any of them since all of them rely on me to remember to explicitly add the port, protocol etc. I find this to be the most elegant way of doing this:

```
full_url = URI( root_url )
full_url.path = Image.first.image.url
# Or maybe you want a link to some asset, like I did:
# full_url.path = image_path("whatevar.jpg")
full_url.to_s
```

And what is the best thing about it is that we can easily change just one thing and no matter what thing that might be you always do it the same way. Say if you wanted to drop the protocol and and use the [The Protocol-relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), do this before the final conversion to string.

```
full_url.scheme = nil
```

Yay, now I have a way of converting my asset image urls to protocol relative urls that I can use on a code snippet that others might want to add on their site and they'll work regardless of the protocol they use on their site (providing that your site supports either protocol).

Answer (score 2):

I used `default_url_options`, because `request` is not available in mailer and avoided duplicating hostname in `config.action_controller.asset_host` if haven't specified it before.

```
config.asset_host = ActionDispatch::Http::URL.url_for(ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to request object in an email, so how about:

```
def image_url(*args)
    raw(image_tag(*args).sub /src="(.*?)"/, "src=\"//#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:protocol]}#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]}" + '\1"')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually easily get this done by

```
root_url[0..-2] + image.url
```

I agree it doesn't look too good, but gets the job done.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this trick to avoid double slash:

```
URI.join(root_url, image.url)
```