# How do I get an absolute URL for an asset in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`image_path` returns a path only (no host).

The `url_for` helper won't accept a single path, so something like `url_for(image_path('image.png'))` wouldn't work. While the internal `url_for` in `ActionDispatch::Http::Url.url_for` would appear to do the trick ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb#L23)), there doesn't seem to be a public interface for it.

How should I go about doing it? Ultimately, it'd be nice to have a function like `image_url` that works like `url_for` does for routes so that I could call `image_url('image.png')` and get the absolute URL given all of the `default_url_options`.

Comment: this blog has a snippet that you can use: http://stick.gk2.sk/blog/2009/12/image_url-function-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: @Spike: the shortcoming with that approach is that it ignores the default url options. There would, for instance, be no way to override the inferred request params either manually or through a default_url_options hash in the app configuration.

Comment: @SpikeGronim This will not work with delayed jobs as request will be empty

Comment: For those on Rails ~> 4.2.1, use `:host` option of `asset_url` and friends, e.g. `asset_url('my_image.png', host: root_url)`. See [asset_url docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/asset_url).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that as of recently, `sass-rails` now interprets the `image_url` command within a scss file in the expected manner, resolving to the final location of the image in question.

Comment: Any way to do this outside of Sass? `image_url` doesn't work in views.

Comment: yep. here's where i've used it before (an inline style): `"background:url(#{asset_path('desktop-header@2x.jpg')}) top center no-repeat;"`

Answer (score 53):

```
def image_url(source)
  URI.join(root_url, image_path(source))
end
```

This way you get url either using `assets_host` or joining with root_url.

Comment: for info you must add `add_template_helper(MailerHelper)` to the mailer to make the helper works in 3.2

Comment: @Syl Why MailerHelper? It is about assets not about mailing

Answer (score 14):

Try this in your `application_helper.rb` (from one of the comments on the page Spike listed):

```
def image_url(source)
  "#{root_url}#{image_path(source)}"
end
```

Comment: To remove the extra slash: `def image_url(source)
    "#{root_url[0...-1]}#{image_path(source)}"
  end`

Comment: I had trouble using this in Rails 3.1 until I changed the name to `url_for_image`. I am not sure, but I think the method `image_url` was being looked for as a route.

Comment: I also had to change image_url method name to get_image_url to get this to work.

Answer (score 6):

Our production and staging assets are on s3/cloudfront... but not locally/dev. So I wrote this (may be overkill, and probably can be simplified):

```
  def get_digest_file(source)
     return asset_path(source.to_s.downcase) unless Rails.application.config.assets.digests.present?
     return ActionController::Base.asset_host + "/assets/" + Rails.application.config.assets.digests[source.to_s.downcase]
  end
```

Comment: this answer is slightly different if using turbo-sprockets, btw.

Answer (score 4):

From [Full url for an image-path in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484809/full-url-for-an-image-path-in-rails-3)

```
request.protocol + request.host_with_port + image_path('image.png')
```

You can even create a helper to DRY it, something like

```
def full_image_path(img_path)
    request.protocol + request.host_with_port + image_path(img_path)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define css with absolute url for any background image or other assets. So you can generate it dynamically following this [How to get absolute image paths in your css files using sass/scss](https://coderwall.com/p/exj0ig).

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-image: image-url(background.png);
}
```

In your environment file change it with yours

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://your.domain.com/"
```

Then your css will look something like that:

```
body {
  background-image: url(http://your.domain.com/assets/background.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having an issue with not being able to reach `root_url` from a view, you can either pass it to the view, or you could also add an `.env` variable and then call it in the root.

```
asset_url('image.png', host: "https://#{ENV['HOSTNAME']}/")
```