# Rails Action Mailer: images in emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm trying to paste images into email. The problem is emails comming without images inside

development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    :host => 'localhost:3000',
    :only_path => false
  }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

view file:

```
<div class="image">
  <%= image_tag image_path('email-logo.png') %>
</div>
```

Where did I make a mistake? Please ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're sending emails from `localhost:3000`, which isn't publicly available (and limited to your machine only).

You have to expose your local environment, so that images can be downloaded in your mail client.

Use service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose your local domain.

Once done, be sure to replace 
`config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'`

with the ngrok URL (something like `config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://<xxx>.ngrok.com'`)

Also, in your view file, you'll have to ensure that you specify the absolute url for the image (and not just the relative path). You can read more on that here: [How do I get an absolute URL for an asset in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500025/how-do-i-get-an-absolute-url-for-an-asset-in-rails-3-1)

Answer (score 30):

try

```
<div class="image">
  <%= image_tag('email-logo.png') %>
</div>
```

Make sure you set `config.action_controller.asset_host` and `config.action_mailer.asset_host`

Comment: Make sure you set `config.action_controller.asset_host` and `config.action_mailer.asset_host` and this works well.

Comment: Setting the two configuration options did it for me! Thanks

Comment: You don't need and probably don't want to set `config.action_controller.asset_host`, as it will give your non-email images full URLs. Just setting `config.action_mailer.asset_host` to something like `http://example.com` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the

```
image_url('e-mail-logo.png')
```

instead of

```
image_path()
```

it will render the absolute path to the image, which should work. The internal path to the image is meaningless in the context of the message.

Comment: The issue is not image_tag, but the fact that local host is not accessible by your email client

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Utsav Kesharwani.
I recently faced the same problem. As the localhost is not publicly available, you cannot access images of localhost.

So, One practical solution to this problem can be to upload your images to cloud and accessing them when you want to display those images.

I personally prefer [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) -- A cloud-based service that provides an end-to-end image management solution including uploads, storage, manipulations, optimizations and delivery.

You can refer to Cloudinary documentation for rails: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration#getting_started_guide

I hope this helps.

Comment: Greetings. Please check out [Take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Answer (score -3):

I am not a rails guru, but I found this one:

1. put your image email-logo.png inside public folder of rails project;
2. in your email (ex. views/devise/mailer/my_email.html.erb, set the image tag like this:

   ```
   <%= image_tag("http://#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]}:#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:port]}/email-logo.png") %>
   ```