# Get full path of file_field image in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, file-upload, filefield

I am trying to get the full path from an image I am uploading with the rails file_field helper.

```
%h4 Upload Image
.col-sm-8
  =label_tag "Upload Image"
.col-sm-4  
  =form_tag(controller:"images", :html => {:multipart => true}) do
    =select("app", "app", ["#{Rails.env}_thing", "#{Rails.env}_otherthing"], {include_blank: true})
    =file_field :post, :image
    %button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block{:type => "submit"}
      ="Upload Image"
```

when it hits the controller action the params are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kVf52OKMdkQPte/jA99R33213123210WRklc2uMhGdM=", "app"=>{"app"=>"development_thing"}, "post"=>{"image"=>"picture.png"}, "html"=>{"multipart"=>"true"}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"images"}
```

What I really want though is the full path of that image file. How would I get that? So if I uploaded from my desktop it would be "/Users/bob/desktop/picture.png"

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full url for an image-path in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484809/full-url-for-an-image-path-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the fullpath of file via input type 'file'. Browser will not allow it. Its a security feature in all modern browsers.

In chrome u will get

```
C:\fakepath\filename.ext
```

while in mozilla u only get filename

```
filename.ext
```

you can find lots of other question related to this.
see

[How to get the full path of the file from a file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176377/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-the-file-from-a-file-input)

[Full path from file input using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489133/full-path-from-file-input-using-jquery)