# How to get absolute paths with javascript_include_tag?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, absolute-path, pdfkit

I'm working on Rails layout for pdf (using Pdfkit) and I need to include my javascript assets with absolute paths (full urls) because wkhtmltopdf doesn't see relative.

this:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

is converted to this:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.position.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.menu.js?body=1"></script>
<!-- MUCH MORE :) -->
```

How can I get the same script tags with full urls?

---

// edit

```
= (javascript_include_tag 'application').gsub('="', "=\"#{ root_url }").html_safe
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939942/generate-full-url-to-javascript-in-rails-similar-to-javascript-path-but-url

Comment: It's not about one file, but about 30, which are in assets pipeline in application.js

Comment: Well, in production they will be compiled into one.

Comment: Yes, I know, but what about development?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
javascript_include_tag('application').delete("\n").gsub('="', "=\"#{ root_url }")
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be the best solution for this case

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', host: request.base_url %>
```